# como listar un directorio por rango de fechas con php

Tags: php, array, php7, function, zip

Tengo un directorio de puro archivos pdf
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que estoy buscando es listarlo por un rango de fechas a traves de la funcion glob de php lo cual no he logrado algun resultado

```
$start = $_POST['desde'];
$end = $_POST['hasta'];

echo $start."<br>"; echo $end. "<BR>";
foreach(glob("PDF/??[$start - $end]*", GLOB_NOCHECK) as $filenames) {
    echo "$filenames";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: para ser especificos tengo un directorio de puro archivos pdf y lo que estoy buscando es listarlo por un rango de fechas a traves de la funcion glob de php lo cual no he logrado algun resultado

Comment: ¿Listar por rango de fechas? En la imagen aparecen varias fechas.

Comment: si de acuerdo a esas fechas establecer un rango para mostrarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si el uso de `glob` te sea estrictamente necesario pero podrías resolverlo con la clase [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.directoryiterator.php).

Crearé una carpeta con algunos ficheros `.pdf`s:

```
$ -> ls -1 pdfs
1.pdf
1.txt
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
5.pdf
```

El código explicado sería el siguiente:

```
<?php

# Pasamos dos fechas:
$startDate = new DateTime('2021-08-30 00:00:01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2021-08-31 23:59:59');

# Instanciamos el iterator indicándole que carpeta deseamos iterar:
$directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator('./pdfs/');

# Recorremos cada fichero:
foreach ($directoryIterator as $file) {
    # Si alguno termina en '.', '..' o el tipo de extensión es distinto a '.pdf' (hay un .txt de prueba en el directorio) entonces pasamos al siguiente fichero: 
    if ($file->isDot() || $file->getExtension() !== 'pdf') {
        continue;
    }

    # Obtenemos el timestamp de modificación de nuestro fichero .pdf:
    $modificationDateTimestamp = $file->getMTime();
    # Verificamos si está entre las dos fechas que hemos pasado obteniendo el timestamp, si es mayor que la fecha de inicio y menor que la de fin:
    if ($modificationDateTimestamp > $startDate->getTimestamp() && $modificationDateTimestamp < $endDate->getTimestamp()) {
        echo $file->getfilename() . " está entre las fechas indicadas \n";
    }
}
```

- Resultado:

```
$ -> php directory_interator_example.php 
2.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
3.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
1.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
5.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
4.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas
```

Nota:

- Para el ejemplo he usado la fecha de modificación del .pdf para comparar: [getMTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/directoryiterator.getmtime.php), en la documentación puedes usar otro tipo de fecha que requieras, por ejemplo la última vez de acceso.

Comment: amigo me muestra todo el directorio a pesar de establecer el rango de las fechas

Comment: He movido este pdf al directorio: `$ -> ls -1 pdfs/
1.pdf
1.txt
2.pdf
3.pdf
4.pdf
5.pdf
cert1.pdf
`  donde la fecha de modificación no está dentro del rango `$ -> stat -c ‘%y’ pdfs/cert1.pdf 
‘2020-10-13 11:51:54.857600102 +0200’
` y aún así no se imprime: `$ -> php directory_interator_example.php 
2.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
3.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
1.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
5.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas 
4.pdf está entre las fechas indicadas ` Adáptalo según como lo necesites pero no debería haber problema en que te funcione.

Comment: gracias amigo @Adrian no me había percatado de la función getMTime busca por fechas de modificación

Comment: De nada. Espero haberte ayudado ;).

Comment: si amigo gracias , una consulta mas se puede comprimir y descargar esos archivos que toma $file???